# Optimize performance of 1920x1080 canvas recording

Tags: javascript, canvas, optimization, webgl, mediarecorder

I would like to make a basic canvas-recorder using the MediaRecorder API to record a webGL (or other) canvas.

I want the final video to be 1920x1080 size (even if the actual resolution is lower, AKA i'm fine with it being scaled up).

The problem is that when I try to load a 1920x1080 canvas and screen record it with WebGL, the results are very jittery and choppy, like, extremely (even though it does record it, choppyness and all).
All I want is the finished **size** of the video to be 1920x1080, even if it's actually lower quality, and I need it to play in real time in a browser, without being choppy. So:

1. Is there any way to make a webGL canvas a bigger size, while keeping the same performance it would have with a smaller size?
2. Is there a way for the mediarecorder API to record a video that has a higher resolution than the stream (in this case, a canvas stream) that it is currently capturing?

Comment: Recording images (even the screen) is a very intensive operation. Most laptops will give you choppy results even if you try to record a portion of the screen.
It really depends on your hardware, but I would advise to scale down the size of the canvas and then scale it up with interpolation (this could happen after recording).

Comment: ideally you want to scale the output video stream, not scale the input data

Comment: @LJᛃ what do you mean? How can I scale a canvas stream without scaling the canvas?

Comment: To be clear, even the live animation is choppy or only the recorded one is? If the former, does it run smoothly when not streaming? Does drawing something less intensive reproduces the same issue? Does this happen with all browsers + codecs? Could you set up a [mcve]?

Comment: @Kaiido its just literally making a canvas with 1920x1080, drawing anything to it,mainly wegl though. it runs kind o choppy before recording starts, though manageable, but when the `canvas.captureStream()` is called, then everything is VERY choppy / unmanageable. So far I've only tested this in chrome and firefox and have gotten same results

Comment: So you are already hitting the machine's limits even before starting the recording right? If you just record a simple square moving on a 2D context, even the recording is smooth? For instance https://jsfiddle.net/gdmpzfus/

Comment: @Kaiido welll kind of, it pretty much works fine before `.captureStream`, but once I call it, even on an almost blank canvas, it starts freaking out and being extremely choppy, but 720/480 works fine

Comment: You are not answering my questions... Hard to help you in this situation. In the fiddle I linked to, is the animation smooth both live and in the recording? If your animation is *barely* smooth to begin with, we'd need to see it to help you optimize it, because adding any overhead will make it choppy, and while it may work @720/480 for some time, it may very well just become choppy later on. So please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

In webgl way you may use `webGlContext.viewport(0, 0, width, height);` this set size of fragments, less width/height value, less quality, more speed)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to reduce canvas size, but keep css style size?

```
<canvas width="192" height="108" style="width:1920px; height:1080px" />
```

Comment: does this keep the resolution to 1920x1080 with the `MediaRecorder` api?

Comment: This suggests yes. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Taking_still_photos#Get_the_video

Answer (score 0):

> *"Is there any way to make a webGL canvas a bigger size, while keeping the same performance it would have with a smaller size?"*

If by *"bigger"* you mean take up more of the page the answer is Yes. Just set the CSS width and height properties to the size you wish, while keeping the canvas width and height properties as they are. With in limits this will have no effect on the performance.

If by *"bigger"* you mean you mean increase the resolution of the canvas then the answer is NO. No matter what GPU you use they all have a rate at which pixels can be rendered, any increase in the number of pixels will result in more time needed to render a given scene. The only option is to upgrade the hardware.

> *"Is there a way for the mediarecorder API to record a video that has a higher resolution than the stream (in this case, a canvas stream) that it is currently capturing?"*

No! and there never will be as there is no need. This is an automatic function of almost all media playback APIs. When the media content is presented to the screen it is scaled to what ever size the user/app wishes.

There are technologies that will upscale (interpolates between pixels) media content but they are all playback technologies.

There is active research into GPU's that upscale ray traced content (GPU based deep convolutional neural networks). However it is not available (via any standardized API) outside experimental GPUs, and may be years before the hardware is available to the market (if ever).

### Reduce recording jank.

All you can do is reduce the workload on the hardware.

- Render the scene at lower resolution to a frame buffer. Then render that buffer to the canvas at the desired resolution. Depending on the scene you can also try a simple [upscale algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_scaling) when you render the frame buffer to the canvas.
- Reduce the quality settings of the GPU.
- Reduce the scene complexity.
- Render the scene via a webworker.
- Use webGL2 rather than webGL.
- Ensure the browser is best setup to capture. Eg on chrome go to [flags](http://chrome://flags/) search the options for anything related to media capture. Again on chrome go to [GPU](http://chrome://gpu/) to check if there are any problems related to the GPU. For other browser check their help to locate similar pages.
- Experiment with different codexs to find the one that best captures the scene.
- Reduce the recording frame rate.
- Ensure the hardware is running lean. (Stop all unneeded processes)
- Use better hardware.

Comment: I mean the commputer itself has 16gb of ram, its just on the browser its slower

Comment: @bluejayke Apart from a minimum need, RAM will make little to no difference. The problem is the performance of the GPU or Integrated GP,  and the CPU and associated hardware. Have you tried a 3rd party native capture app to capture the page content (if that is an option?)

Comment: yes ves Ive tried 3rd party capture (or even getdisplaymedia whch is a LOT faster), but the problem is that its not able to capture 1920x1080, snce my actual screen size s smaller than that... so what do I do?

Comment: "No! and there never will be as there is no need." [There will be, there will be...](https://github.com/WICG/web-codecs/blob/master/explainer.md#example-of-real-time-communication-using-svc)